# How to download/store videos into database using java?

Tags: java, database, video

I want to write a program which allows me to download the video of a certain link and store it into database. I am able to retrieve the link of the video but I can't download it into my computer or database. Lets say my link is "www.abcde.com/12345" and when i click this link, I can watch the video. So How do I download/store this video into my database using java ? I read about inputstream, httpconnection and getV , filereader and whatnot but I just dont know where to start.

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Link

The link you enter by browser to watch a video is rather not going to be link which you can use in your application to download the content of a file. Link you enter by browser is probably a reference to some web video player

In your java application a link to original resource file with the video content will be neccessary.

### 2. Database storage of a video

Do you really need to store video content in a database?

There are plenty more options (like for example storing only reference to file path)

I reccomend you to read this article
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB